# Is there a visual component in flex which will allow me to edit style declarations?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, coding-style, components

I imagine changing the styling is a common requirement. Say a user wishes to change the background colour and the font style. I'm looking for a component fit into any flex application and edit the style sheets.

I know I can build one from scratch using the (get/set)Style methods and using the StyleManager class, however I didn't want to "reinvent the wheel." I assume there is a component that someone has already written - google hasn't thrown up a suitable candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such base component. Setting styles is very personal, so there's no common solution.
BTW, look up [here](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html)